How to Click other program's WinApi button from VBA in Excel spreadsheet?
I am trying to solve a problem when PostMessage or SendMessage do not work from Excel VBA explicitly. I.e. producing no results.
//Previously I met similar problem when trying to execute CopyFileEx with parallel unattended write from a buffer with a callback to a module function. it did nothing//
Lets start that I found the window handle (using samples and chatgpt help) using EnumWindows.
I.e. I have external program process ID, and its handle.
Then using EnumChildWindows I get a button handle and its ID.
With this I can bring the window on top, make it focused, and even extract all its metrics, and the required button metrics.
Then in a spreadsheet, or in a module (tried both) I attempt to send messages like clicking the button.
Sub Main 
        currentThreadID = GetCurrentThreadId()
    
        ' Attach the input threads
        AttachThreadInput currentThreadID, targetThreadID, True


       wParam = MAKEWPARAM(buttonID, WM_LBUTTONDOWN)
        result = PostMessage(targetwHnd, WM_COMMAND, wParam, buttonHnd)

        wParam = MAKEWPARAM(buttonID, WM_LBUTTONUP)
        result = PostMessage(targetwHnd, WM_COMMAND, wParam, buttonHnd)


        wParam = MAKEWPARAM(buttonID, BN_CLICKED) 
        result = PostMessage(targetwHnd, WM_COMMAND, wParam, buttonHnd)


        AttachThreadInput currentThreadID, targetThreadID, False
End Sub

Public Function MAKEWPARAM(ByVal low As Integer, ByVal high As Integer) As Long
    MAKEWPARAM = (CLng(high) * &H10000) Or (low And &HFFFF)
End Function


And nothing happens.
When tried controlling mouse, bringing coursor and commanding mouse coursor to click, it works. But this disturbs the workflow. I want to activate the button using messages.

Maybe it's a lot of lines, but it might be better to post a full set of code, even if it doesn't work.  There's not much for anyone to latch onto here if they wanted to try it out, without reproducing your whole process.
